# Having trouble understanding the upper bound and lower bound in the following R code

Tags: r, statistics, measurement

I have pasted the code i am having an issue with at the end. It contains R command lines to display the observed proportions of correct response over the ability score levels for group 1.
The lower bound of ability for group 1 is speciﬁed with t1l that implies theta- 1-lower; the upper bound of ability for group 1 is speciﬁed with t1u that implies theta-1-upper:
Before this code there was another code which defined theta as following:

```
theta <- seq(-3, 3, .1875)
f <- rep(21, length(theta))
```

Then this code was mentioned. What i understand is that this code is finding some values between 2 bounds. However feel that if i want to find something in between 1 and 3 then i should make a code which says i want to find values less than 3 and more than 1.
However this code  does this for the lower bound

```
theta[g] <= t2l) { lowerg1 <- lowerg1 + 1 }
```

This means it finds values less than 1? Values less than 1 would be something like 0 , -1 -2 etc and we want to find values in BETWEEN 1 and 3. I feel we should instead say theta[g] >= t2l) so that i can find values larger than 1 so i can find values like 2 which is between 3 and 1
It does the same thing for upper bound. but this will find ALL values below 3 not just between 3 and 1

```
theta[g] <= t2u)
```

This is how i am visualizing things to be going  on
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPiiS.png
And this is how i feel things should be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyly1.png

```
t2l <- 1
t2u <- 3
lowerg1 <- 0
for (g in 1:length(theta)) {
if (theta[g] <= t2l) { lowerg1 <- lowerg1 + 1 }
}
upperg1 <- 0
for (g in 1:length(theta)) {
if (theta[g] <= t2u) { upperg1 <- upperg1 + 1 }
}
theta2 <- theta[lowerg1:upperg1]
p2 <- p[lowerg1:upperg1]
if (mdl == 1) { maintext <- paste("Group 2", "\n") }
if (mdl == 2) { maintext <- paste("Group 2", "\n") }
if (mdl == 3) { maintext <- paste("Group 2", "\n") }
plot(theta2, p2, xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(0,1),
xlab="Ability", ylab="Probability of Correct Response",
main=maintext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code below does exactly what it is supposed to do

```
t2l <- 1
t2u <- 3
lowerg1 <- 0
for (g in 1:length(theta)) {
  if (theta[g] <= t2l) { lowerg1 <- lowerg1 + 1 }
}
upperg1 <- 0
for (g in 1:length(theta)) {
  if (theta[g] <= t2u) { upperg1 <- upperg1 + 1 }
}
theta2 <- theta[lowerg1:upperg1]
```

The last time `theta[g] <= t2l` was when `theta` was `0.9375` and `lowerg1` is `22`.

A simpler way to define theta2 is shown below

```
theta2 <- theta %>% subset(theta>=t2l & theta<=t2u)
```

Comment: Thanks i got it. I am very new to R and i was confusing over some things , however they got resolved. I did not know about the concept of index and this post basically helped me clear it
https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/j54an6/is_this_code_given_in_book_wrong/

Comment: So i think by using your method , our full code would look like this ?
t2l <- 1
t2u <- 3
theta2 <- theta %>% subset(theta>=t2l & theta<=t2u)

Comment: Your previous logic had one extra element 0.9375 which is <1.  To not include that it should have started as lowerg1 <- 1 and not 0.